# python lemmatizer that lemmatize "political" and "politics" to the same word

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

I've been testing different python lemmatizers for a solution I'm building out. One difficult problem I've faced is that stemmers are producing non english words which won't work for my use case. Although stemmers get "politics" and "political" to the same stem correctly, I'd like to do this with a lemmatizer, but spacy and nltk are producing different words for "political" and "politics". Does anyone know of a more powerful lemmatizer? My ideal solution would look like this:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

print("political = ", lemmatizer.lemmatize("political"))
print("politics = ", lemmatizer.lemmatize("politics"))
```

returning:

```
political =  political
politics =  politics
```

Where I want to return:

```
political =  politics
politics =  politics
```

Comment: Because "political" is a lemma and so is "politics" a lemma. Note: Lemma is not a "root" meaning/word.

Comment: i'm aware, just wondering if there is a tool to reduce the words as i described that is not stemming.

Comment: Are you only interested in doing this for adjective/adverbs?

Comment: Be careful, if you're just looking for a tool, someone might come closing the question as asking for tool =)

Comment: tool or collection of algorithms, as you found independently polite and political are opposite meanings that are getting confused in stemmers, which forces me to use lemmatizers. I think my solution may not have been created before, and i'm converging on a mixture of spell checking, stemming, and lemmatizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a lemma is not a "root" word as you thought it to be. It's just a form that exist in the dictionary and for English in NLTK `WordNetLemmatizer` the dictionary is WordNet and as long as the dictionary entry is in WordNet it is a lemma, there are entries for "political" and "politics", so they're valid lemma:

```
from itertools import chain
print(set(chain(*[ss.lemma_names() for ss in wn.synsets('political')])))
print(set(chain(*[ss.lemma_names() for ss in wn.synsets('politics')])))
```

[out]:

```
{'political'}
{'political_sympathies', 'political_relation', 'government', 'politics', 'political_science'}
```

Maybe there are other tools out there that can do that, but I'll try this as a first.

First, stem all lemma names and group the lemmas with the same stem:

```
from collections import defaultdict

from wn import WordNet
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

porter = PorterStemmer()
wn = WordNet()

x = defaultdict(set)
i = 0
for lemma_name in wn.all_lemma_names():
    if lemma_name:
        x[porter.stem(lemma_name)].add(lemma_name)
        i += 1
```

**Note:** `pip install -U wn`

Then as a sanity check, we check that the no. of lemmas > no. of groups:

```
print(len(x.keys()), i)
```

[out]:

```
(128442, 147306)
```

Then we can take a look at the groupings:

```
for k in sorted(x):
    if len(x[k]) > 1:
        print(k, x[k])
```

It seems to do what we need to group the words together with their "root word", e.g.

```
poke {'poke', 'poking'}
polar {'polarize', 'polarity', 'polarization', 'polar'}
polaris {'polarisation', 'polarise'}
pole_jump {'pole_jumping', 'pole_jumper', 'pole_jump'}
pole_vault {'pole_vaulter', 'pole_vault', 'pole_vaulting'}
poleax {'poleaxe', 'poleax'}
polem {'polemically', 'polemics', 'polemic', 'polemical', 'polemize'}
police_st {'police_state', 'police_station'}
polish {'polished', 'polisher', 'polish', 'polishing'}
polit {'politics', 'politic', 'politeness', 'polite', 'politically', 'politely', 'political'}
poll {'poll', 'polls'}
```

But if we look closer there is some confusion:

```
polit {'politics', 'politic', 'politeness', 'polite', 'politically', 'politely', 'political'}
```

So I would suggest the next step is

**to loop through the groupings again and run some semantics and check the "relatedness" of the words and split the words that might not be related**, maybe try something like Universal Sentence Encoder, e.g. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BM-eKdFb2G2zXqNt3dHgVm4gH8PaPJOq (might not be a trivial task)

Or do **some manual work and reorder the groupings**. (The heavy lifting of the work is already done by the porter stemmer in the grouping, now it's time to do some human work)

Then you'll have to somehow find the root among each group of words (i.e. prototype/label for the cluster).

Finally using the resource of groups of words you've created, you can not "find the root word.

Comment: thanks, I think this may be a more challenging problem than I thought. My other attempts are running into the same problem of mixing polite and politics/political, which is why I was after a lemmatizer. I am currently exploring a hybrid stem, lemmatize, spell checker combo